# Collect data from word files using regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to collect data from a few word files that have the same structure and put them in a dataframe. Every file has one field for company name a and few fields for deals name & deal value. The problem I have is that I cant find a way to put the data in the correct way so I can know for which company is the data regarding.

```
import docx2txt
import re
import docx 
import glob
import pandas as pd
text = ''
for file in glob.glob('D:/Projects/Word reader/*.docx'):
    text += docx2txt.process(file)
```

The text : - 'Your details:\n\n\n\nFirm name:\n\nCompany A\n\nLocation (jurisdiction):\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nn\n\n\n\n\nDEAL \n\n\n\nDeal name:\n\nApple \n\nDate completed (must have closed in 2020):\n\n19883\n\nCross-border: (Y/N)\n\n\n\nValue (USD):\n\n3 million\n\nClient(s) advised:\n\n\n\n\n\nDEAL \n\n\n\nDeal name:\n\n\tAmazon\n\nDate completed (must have closed in 2020):\n\n\n\nCross-border: (Y/N)\n\n\n\nValue (USD):\n\n1 billion \n\nClient(s) advised:\n\n\n\nClient contact and email: (clients will be contacted anonymously)\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nDEAL \n\n\n\nDeal name:\n\n\tMicrosoft\n\nDate completed (must have closed in 2020):\n\n\n\nCross-border: (Y/N)\n\n\n\nValue (USD):\n\n1 million\n\nClient(s) advised:\n\n\n\nClient contact and email: (clients will be contacted anonymously)Your details:\n\n\n\nFirm name:\n\nCompany B\n\nLocation (jurisdiction):\n\n\n\n\n\n\nn\n\n\nDEAL \n\n\n\nDeal name:\n\nTesla \n\nDate completed (must have closed in 2020):\n\n\n\nCross-border: (Y/N)\n\n\n\nValue (USD):\n\n88 milions\n\nClient(s) advised:\n\n\n\nn\n\nDEAL \n\n\n\nDeal name:\n\n\tTest Data 3\n\nDate completed (must have closed in 2020):\n\n\n\nCross-border: (Y/N)\n\n\n\nValue (USD):\n\nNo data\n\nClient(s) advised:\n\n\n\nClient contact and email: (clients will be contacted anonymously)\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nDEAL \n\n\n\nDeal name:\n\n\tTest Data\n\nDate completed (must have closed in 2020):\n\n\n\nCross-border: (Y/N)\n\n\n\nValue (USD):\n\n45 billions\n\nClient(s) advised:\n\n\n)'

Also I have problem with the regex data with the symbol " : "

```
CompanyName = re.findall(r'Firm name:\n\n(.*?)\s\nLocation', text, re.DOTALL)
DealName = re.findall(r'Deal name:\n\n(.*?)\s*Date', text, re.DOTALL)
DealValue = re.findall(r'Value (USD)*(.*?)\s*Client', text, re.DOTALL)
df = pd.DataFrame([CompanyName,DealName,DealValue])
```

[image]

The end results I need is :

| Company Name | Deal Name | Deal Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Company A | Apple | 3 million |
| Company A | Amazon | 1 billion |
| Company B | Tesla | 88 milions |
| Company B | Test Data 3 | No Data |

Comment: Are there literally `\n` sequences or is that supposed to represent actual newlines?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest splitting the text into sections first, each for individual company. Then, you may extract all deal names and values, and then build the dataframe data assuming there is a deal value for each deal name:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
s =  'Your details:\n\n\n\nFirm name:\n\nCompany A\n\nLocation (jurisdiction):\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nn\n\n\n\n\nDEAL \n\n\n\nDeal name:\n\nApple \n\nDate completed (must have closed in 2020):\n\n19883\n\nCross-border: (Y/N)\n\n\n\nValue (USD):\n\n3 million\n\nClient(s) advised:\n\n\n\n\n\nDEAL \n\n\n\nDeal name:\n\n\tAmazon\n\nDate completed (must have closed in 2020):\n\n\n\nCross-border: (Y/N)\n\n\n\nValue (USD):\n\n1 billion \n\nClient(s) advised:\n\n\n\nClient contact and email: (clients will be contacted anonymously)\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nDEAL \n\n\n\nDeal name:\n\n\tMicrosoft\n\nDate completed (must have closed in 2020):\n\n\n\nCross-border: (Y/N)\n\n\n\nValue (USD):\n\n1 million\n\nClient(s) advised:\n\n\n\nClient contact and email: (clients will be contacted anonymously)Your details:\n\n\n\nFirm name:\n\nCompany B\n\nLocation (jurisdiction):\n\n\n\n\n\n\nn\n\n\nDEAL \n\n\n\nDeal name:\n\nTesla \n\nDate completed (must have closed in 2020):\n\n\n\nCross-border: (Y/N)\n\n\n\nValue (USD):\n\n88 milions\n\nClient(s) advised:\n\n\n\nn\n\nDEAL \n\n\n\nDeal name:\n\n\tTest Data 3\n\nDate completed (must have closed in 2020):\n\n\n\nCross-border: (Y/N)\n\n\n\nValue (USD):\n\nNo data\n\nClient(s) advised:\n\n\n\nClient contact and email: (clients will be contacted anonymously)\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nDEAL \n\n\n\nDeal name:\n\n\tTest Data\n\nDate completed (must have closed in 2020):\n\n\n\nCross-border: (Y/N)\n\n\n\nValue (USD):\n\n45 billions\n\nClient(s) advised:\n\n\n)'

sections = re.findall(r"^Firm name:.*?(?=\nFirm name:|\Z)", s, re.M | re.S)
data = []
for section in sections:
  company = list(filter(None, section.splitlines()))[1]
  deal_names  = re.findall(r'^Deal name:\s*(.+)', section, re.M)
  deal_values = re.findall(r'^Value \(USD\):\s*(.+)', section, re.M)
  for i, _ in enumerate(deal_names):
      data.append([company.strip(), deal_names[i].strip(), deal_values[i].strip()])

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['Company Name', 'Deal Name', 'Deal Value']
```

Output:

```py
>>> df
  Company Name    Deal Name   Deal Value
0    Company A       Apple     3 million
1    Company A       Amazon   1 billion 
2    Company A    Microsoft    1 million
3    Company B       Tesla    88 milions
4    Company B  Test Data 3      No data
5    Company B    Test Data  45 billions
```

NOTE:

- I assume the second line in each section is the company name (that is just clear from your data), that's why I used `list(filter(None, section.splitlines()))[1]`
- Splitting into sections is done with `(?sm)^Firm name:.*?(?=\nFirm name:|\Z)`, see the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/jnFEtO/2).
- The other two patterns start with `^` that matches *line start positions* due to `re.M` flag.
- To match literal parentheses, you need to escape them with `\` in the regex pattern.